# Basic facts about the join of two varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $Y\subseteq X$ be a smooth subvariety of the smooth projective variety $X\subseteq\mathbb{P}^{N}$. Let us consider
$$
S_{X,Y}:=\overline{\{(x,y,z)\in X\times Y\times \mathbb{P}^{N}:x\neq y, z\in\langle x,y\rangle\}}.
$$
We define the join $S(X,Y)$ of $X$ and $Y$ to be the image of $S_{X,Y}$ under the third projection. My questions are:

$i)$ If $z\in S(X,Y)$ but there is no $(x,y)\in X\times Y$ such that $x\neq y$ and $z\in\langle x,y\rangle$, is it true that $z\in T_{y}X$ for certain $y\in Y$?

$ii)$ Is there an open subset $U\subseteq S(X,Y)$ such that for every point $z\in U$ there exist $(x,y)\in X\times Y$ such that $x\neq y$ and $z\in\langle x,y\rangle$?

I have read some texts where (in my opinion) these assertions are implicitly assumed, but I haven't been able to find/figure out a proof.

Comment: (i) Yes (and this works even if $X$ and $Y$ are not smooth).
(ii) You need either to accept $U=\emptyset$ or to at least exclude limit cases such as $X=Y={\rm point}$.

Arguments for the proof can be found in books like Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry* (see the proof of Bertini's theorem, II.8.18, for example).